# Copying database rows in .csv file takes too long

Tags: database, sqlite, laravel-5

I want to copy files from a database into a file .csv. Is use this code

```
        $whatday=\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString();
        $file = fopen('/var/www/laravel/public/'.$whatday.'.csv', 'w');
        fwrite($file, '[OPTION1];[OPTION2]'.PHP_EOL);
        $data=\App\Status::all();
        foreach($data as $dt)
        {
            $col1= $dt->opt1;
            $col2= $dt->opt2;
            fwrite($file,
                        $col1.';'.
                        $col2.';'
                    .PHP_EOL);
            }
        } 

        fclose($file);
```

If the rows in database are few I don't have problems (takes a few seconds), but if the rows are many (>10000, I work with this volumes of data) the copy of the rows takes 1 hour more or less. 
**My question is:**
Are  There  other functions faster ? Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all inserts in one single transaction.